# Are DTO Classes inherently included when using the .Net Core Entity Framework Code First approach?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

Using the Database-First EF model my DTO classes had a clear separation from the actual Database models created by EF. This provisioned a flexible architecture as the DTO and model weren't tightly coupled.

Using Code-First (which I've typically not used as often); I have come across a scenario where when I am adding a migration I get an error:

**The Entity Type '[EntityTypeName]' requires a primary key to be defined**.

The EntityType in this case is actually defined within one of my DTO classes and isn't intended to be the actual replica of any field in the corresponding Database model. It is a class created to facilitate Serialization data transfer of a JSON object from my API to the database.

But the real question is what concern or relevance is that of EF as it does not specifically relate to the underlying Database Model?

Is there something or someway I can alleviate the error to add my migration? Or is this a default behavior when using the .NET Core Code-First approach that can possibly be disabled? The build of the Solution is fine, it's just EF complaining.

Comment: If EF is trying to pull the model into the DB schema then you must have created a relationship or property that references this DTO. Code-first will walk the stack from your DBContext to determine the tables. So make sure the DbContext does not have any direct or indirect reference to your DTOs. Usually the DTOs would be in a separate project so it would be easy separate these concerns. Either way we need to see some code so we can tell you what you have done wrong. Show a section of your DbContext and the Class reference that is linking in the DTO

Comment: Did you seriously name your type `EntityTypeName`?

Comment: Thanks, I will comb through the solution again and see where the non obvious flaw is causing the error. Your explanation sounds very plausible and would explain a lot once I can find the core reason of the issue. Once I acquire it I will post the findings. May help someone else with a similar issue down the line...... and no, EntityTypeName was a placeholder in the question to keep it generic. Thanks

Comment: I know ;) It sometimes masks the issue if we try too hard to anonymize or abstract the types and error messages in posts. There is nothing new out there, we're not going to steal your secrets. Hang in there, I find Code-First is far easier to configure compared to db-first, I've never looked back.